# Non-root login on EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, login

I have set up an EC2 instance with ArchLinux for a client, and I am currently in the testing phase.

I am using PuTTY from Windows 8 to SSH into the machine. I have set up the connection profile correctly, and specified the correct key file.

When trying to login, I am presented with the option to choose which user I want to login as. I choose "root" and the connection proceeds with no problem, though I am not asked for the root password.

I want to forbid root logins, but when trying to login as any other user I get from the system:

```
Server refused our key
```

Also I get a popup window saying:

```
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Why is it that I cannot login as any other user? It is very important for me to forbid root logins.

On a side note, is it normal that I am not prompted for the root password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your public SSH key is installed into the `/home/non-root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the `non-root` user.  The `Server refused our key` message suggests that it isn't or isn't installed correctly.

If you want to use the same SSH key for both `root` and your `non-root` users, it might be as simple as copying the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file into `/home/non-root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Also the message `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)` seems to suggest that this SSH server is only configured to allow authentication with SSH keys.  If you want to allow password-based authentication also, add `PasswordAuthentication yes` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and restart `sshd`.

As for not being prompted for `root` password when logging in as `root`, by default, SSH server is configured to prefer SSH key authentication over passwords, so if that succeeds, you aren't asked for the password.

[ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys) has more info on using SSH keys that might be of use too.

Comment: Will try and report back. Covered pretty much everything! Also, the Arch wiki, though very good, confused me a bit on this topic.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Unfortunately copying the key to the .ssh subdirectory of the non-root user did not do the trick. May have something to do with the AMI, perhaps the "root" username is hardcoded into the key some way or another.